# How to get a class attribute depending on a string in python

Tags: python, string, class, attributes

I have a class in python and I'd like to get one of several attributes depending on a string like this:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att1=1
        self.att2=2
        self.att3=3

    def getatt (self, number):
        return self.att(number)
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def getatt(self, number):
    return getattr(self, 'att%d' % number)
```

Or with new style formatting:

```
def getatt(self, number):
    return getattr(self, 'att{}'.format(number))
```

Also note that if you have many of these attributes, you should perhaps consider storing a list and retrieve elements from their index.

Comment: if there is a meaning to the names and you also want lookup by numbers, also take a look at [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
class My_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
    def getatt(self, number):
        return self.att[number]
    def __getattr__(self, attname):
        if attname.startswith('att') and attname != 'att':
            try: num = int(attname[3:])
            except ValueError: pass
            else: return self.att[num]
        raise AttributeError(attname)
```

(untested)

With this, you can access your data bundled and as well as attributes if needed.